# Duplicate memcached objects

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I am using Memcached to store some PHP objects- lets say my object is a can of soda. Right now my memcached key for Pepsi is 4. So when I get 'soda_4' I get the Pepsi object.

The problem is that sometimes I know I need Pepsi, but I don't have the ID for it. So I need to make a DB call to get the ID before I can get the memcached object. This seems inefficient.

What would be perfect is if I could reference the same object by 2 keys (every time I save the object I have both the ID and Name).

At this point I'm considering saving 2 copies each time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using the number 4?  Why not just use a key called soda_pepsi?

Comment: Lets just say its an efficiency decision that is already built into the system.

Comment: I'm thinking that what I want is probably not possible (with >1 memcached server) because the key determines which server you address- so 1 object can't have 2 keys that would put it on 2 different servers.

Comment: just do make another memcache key to resolve names to id. there isn't any way to do this in one call that I can see without restructuring your key formatting.

Answer (score 2):

**Method A:-**

1. using two caches
2. key A = "name" => "id" (pepsi => 4)
3. key B = "id (details of pepsi)

So, you can have reference to key B when you have object name.
The drawback is you have to make two calls.

**Method B**

You have already mentioned, create two cache using name and id as key.
The drawback is you are duplicating the data.
So, the capacity of memcache will reduce 50%.

I would prefer your suggestion, however